# External access to big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to grant an external organisation access to my bigquery account. Currently I'm using Skyvia to port the data across but this is a very expensive way of doing so.

Running a skyvia pipeline but this is very expensive when I just want to let them look from their external bq account at my bq account